# Playing with selects and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is:

```
<select name='main'>
   <option>Animals</option>
   <option>Food</option>
   <option>Cars</option>
</select>

<select name='other'>
   <option>Rats</option>
   <option>Cats</option>
   <option>Oranges</option>
   <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I filter my second `<select>`, so it would only show items which I want eg. if I choose Animals, my select would be:

```
<select name='other'>
   <option>Rats</option>
   <option>Cats</option>
</select>
```

and if I choose "Food", my `<select>` would look like:

```
<select name='other'>
   <option>Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Well, I hope you get the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to create some kind of association between the selects, I'd recommend using the `data-*` attribute:

```
<select id="main_select" name='main'>
  <option>Animals</option>
  <option>Food</option>
  <option>Cars</option>
</select>

<select id="other_select" name='other'>
  <option data-category="Animals">Rats</option>
  <option data-category="Animals">Cats</option>
  <option data-category="Food">Oranges</option>
  <option data-category="Cars">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Once that's in place for all of the `<option>` elements, the JavaScript code would look something like this:

**EDITED**, this works:

```
$(function() {
   var cloned = $('#other_select option').clone();
   $('#main_select').change(function() {
      var selectedCategory = $(':selected', this).text();
      var filtered = $(cloned).filter("[data-category='" + selectedCategory + "']");
      $("#other_select option").replaceWith(filtered);
   });
   $('#main_select').change(); //fire the event initially.
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RD5Vt/2/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I've put the jquery code in <head> and my selects looks like this: 
<select name='talents'>
<option data-category='Any'>Any</option>
<option data-category='Food'>Oranges</option>
<option data-category='Food'>Apples</option>
<option data-category='Food'>Pears</option>
</select>

Comment: @Tom, I updated my answer around an hour ago, can you please try it.

Comment: Thanks, that really worked better, but how do I make "selected" work? Atm it's selecting the last option and "selected" seems to be ignored.

Comment: @Tom Please explain - doesn't the jsFiddle example do exactly what you want?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin yes it does, "selected" attributed doesn't work with it or at least I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: @Tom What do you mean? Show me an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin try doing <option data-category="Animals" selected>Rats</option>, it won't work.

Comment: @Tom The selected attribute needs to be selected="selected"

Comment: @Jacob Relkin still no effect, try it yourself

Comment: @Jacob Relkin http://jsfiddle.net/7Vcy4/ try this, if first select has an option selected, second select will ignore it's selected="selected"

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `change` event handler to the `main` select box that then branches on which option was selected and then dynamically adds options to the `other` select.  The following assumes a select with id `main` and id `other`:

HTML:

```
<select name="main" id="main">
    <option value="1">Cars</option>
    <option value="2">Food</option>
    <option value="3">Animals</option>
</select>
<!-- Default the other select to 'cars' -->
<select name="other" id="other">
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#main").bind("change", function() {
    var categories = $("#other").get(0);
    categories.options.length = 0;

    switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
            categories.options[0] = new Option("Audi", "Audi");
        break;
    case "2":
            categories.options[0] = new Option("Oranges", "Oranges");
        break;
    case "3":
            categories.options[0] = new Option("Rats", "Rats");
            categories.options[1] = new Option("Cats", "Cats");
        break;
    }
});
```

Check out an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/nRGC9/

Comment: Do you think my solution is, well, better?

Comment: @Jacob: It removes lots of the logic that my solution has, so in that sense, yes.  However the data-* attribute wont validate under HTML 4.  Not sure if the OP cares about that or not though.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please explain? This is just an another way of accomplishing this (as opposed to Jacob's answer).  Also, it's the same as Amjad's answer, which was not downvoted.  The answer is not technically incorrect, and I even provided a working example.

Answer (score -1):

The naive solution would be:

```
 $('select [name=main]').change(function(){
         var other = $('select [name=other] option');
         switch($(this).val()){
              case 'Animals':
                   other.each(function () { if (!isAnimal($(this).val()))
                                                    $(this).hide();
                                           else 
                                                    $(this).show();
                              }); 

//where isAnimal is a function that accepts a string parameter and checks whether its an animal or not
              break;
              case 'food':
                   //continue in the same manner......
    }});
```